# Laravel blade view relative path

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel, laravel-5

I need help with my Laravel Blade view. Currently i'm using `<link href="{{asset('css/sample.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">` to generate the path to my sample.css in my public folder every time. Which it'll generate something like `<link href="http://mydomainname/css/sample.css" rel="stylesheet">` and it's working well *(my public folder is on my public_html folder cpanel hosting)*.

However, i want to use a relative path instead of direct link to my css file. I want to use an easier approach like `<link href="css/sample.css" rel="stylesheet">`, it works if im working on the root route, but it's not working when it goes into deeper route of my website.

Can anyone help how to generate the relative path to my css file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved by modifying `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php` into :

```
function asset($path, $secure = null)
{
    $url = app('url')->asset($path, $secure);
    return parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
}
```

all the `asset()` code in my laravel now produce only the path (by removing the domain URL) and works either on my production or localhost

Answer (score 4):

This is achievable using the easier approach you suggest, you are just missing one `/`.

If you link to your CSS file using a path like this; `/css/sample.css` then it tells the browser to fetch that document in relation to the root URL. This is the same for any asset you use.

So as an HTML link it would be:

```
<link href="/css/sample.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This would tell the browser, no matter what page you are on, to fetch the `sample.css` file from `http(s)://example.com/css/sample.css`.

Without the `/` at the beginning, your link is saying fetch it in relation to the current page; `http(s)://example.com/your/page/url/css/sample.css`. On your homepage this will obviously be successful as the URL would still resolve to `http(s)://example.com/css/sample.css`.

Comment: hello, yes i have tried it and this is the best approach by adding `/`. however, it's not working on my localhost `http://localhost/myprojectname/public/css/sample.css` will be produced if i used the `/css/sample.css` code. I can work with this in my production server, but not on my localhost

Comment: Why can you not use this on your localhost? Remember you can always edit your hosts file to map a URL back to your local dev environment to make this work. E.g create an entry for myproject.dev to direct to 127.0.0.1 and then just update your vhost on apache or the equivalent on your web server. This is why `asset()` is such a great helper, as it works around this issue by using whatever the URL is in the current environment.

Comment: Yes, but asset() will produce a hyperlink instead of local directory. I tried to optimize my website with google PageSpeed and the main problem is asset() will generate a full link which is directly went into my own domain. i have solved this issue by override the asset() helper and remove the URL generated by using parse_url. Thanks for your help James.

Comment: @efraim I don’t see how having a relative URL over a full URL will make your page load any faster. They both still resolve to the same location!

Comment: it was suggested by pagespeed https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

Comment: @efraim I could be wrong, as I don't know how intelligent that tool is, however it could be suggesting that you change it to a relative path as it detects the fact that `asset()` generates a URL that "looks" external. Generally speaking it is faster to load resources locally than to reference them externally via another site or CDN. Obviously a relative path has to be a local resource, but it could just be a red-herring in this case. You could always do your own benchmarking to test this - however I am 99% sure that referencing a local file relatively or by URL will yield the same speed.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/where-do-you-set-public-directory-laravel-5) you just need to edit your `index.php` that located in `public` folder like below :

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

// set the public path to this directory
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
});
```